# Создание многоуровневого списка (HTML, MySql, PHP)

Tags: php, html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица, записи которой необходимо вывести многоуровневым раскрывающимся списком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Записи группируются на основании кода. При клике на группу должны выводиться ее подгруппы.
 Как грамотно это реализовать?
Группы оформил как ссылки, при клике делает запрос в бд и возвращает подгруппы. Как после каждого такого запроса формировать новую разметку страницы?

Решено с помощью скрипта:[bootstrap-treeview](http://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview)

Comment: мне вот не понятно, как вы пытаетесь выводить это дерево, и как у вас меняется разметка. но аякс вам в помощь

Comment: спасибо @teran аякс действительно помог, отредактировал вопрос, добавил ссылку на скрипт с помощью которого решил задачу